# Python Selenium: Alternative to string formatting for lists?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to take the value from the input and put it into the `browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='v1Nh3 kIKUG  _bz0w']")` function. However, the string formatting surely doesn't work, since it's the list, hence it throws the AttributeError.

Does anyone know any alternatives to use with lists (possibly without iterating over each file)?

```
xpath_to_links = input('Enter the xpath to links: ')
posts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='{}']").format(devops)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: Selenium can interact one element at a time. You are gonna have to loop over the elements unless you execute some Javascript wizardry.

Comment: Since I am a beginner, I am a bit stuck writing a list comprehension for that, should it look like that [browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='{}']").format(devops) for link in browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/titovby/?hl=ru'))]?

Comment: I'd advise not to go directly to list comprehension if you are beginner. Try simple FOR  loops. `el =  = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='{}']")` and then based on the range, iterate over each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the reason of error is that you are placing the format function in the wrong place, so instead of operating on string `"//div[@class='{}']"` you call it for the list returned by `find_elements_by_xpath`. Could you please try to replace your code with one of the following lines ?

```
posts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='{}']".format(devops))
posts = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='{devops}']")
```

Comment: Both worked perfectly well - thank you. Could you guide me to any links that would build my understanding around my mistake?

Comment: Can't provide links, but I can provide you with some intuition. Even though the python is not statically typed (you don't need to write it's type in front of every variable ,as you are doing for example in Java, C#, C++, etc), there are still types, that are in fact classes with defined methods on it. So in our case the `str` type has method `format` that returns string concatenation  of existing string and sting provided as an argument. Other type, that is a list, doesn't have this attribute(method) so when you are trying to call it you see an error.

Comment: In fact the reason is misprint in your code. As I told before, instead of calling format method on `str` type, you are calling it on `list`, that simply doesn't have such method.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/
Here is also a good material about string formatting in python

Comment: Thank you again, I got where my mistake was hidden.